# LWC: add new values to existing array

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, array

I have a multi select lookup component allowing users to select multiple accounts.
My issue is that I am unable to add more accounts to the existing list

[image]

Let's say I have 2 existing accounts on my selectedList of records (Tenet Corporation & Umbrella Corp) and I try to add another account to the existing list.
I am not able to.

The selectedRecords are stored in this manner

```
setSelectedRecord(event) {
    var recId = event.currentTarget.dataset.id;
    var selectName = event.currentTarget.dataset.name;
    let newsObject = { 'recId' : recId ,'recName' : selectName };
    this.selectedRecords.push(newsObject);
    this.txtclassname =  'slds-combobox slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click';
    let selRecords = this.selectedRecords;
    this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input').forEach(each => {
        each.value = '';
    });
    console.log('SelectedRecord:::::'+JSON.stringify(this.selectedRecords));
    const selectedEvent = new CustomEvent('selected', { detail: {selRecords}, });
    // Dispatches the event.
    this.dispatchEvent(selectedEvent);
}
```

I was hoping that by doing this

```
 addRecord (event) {
    var recId = event.currentTarget.dataset.id;
    var selectName = event.currentTarget.dataset.name;
    let newsObject = { 'recId' : recId ,'recName' : selectName };

    for(let i = 0; i < this.selectedRecords.length; i++) {
        if(event.detail.name !== this.selectedRecords[i].recId)
            this.selectedRecords.push(newsObject);
    }
    console.log('addRecord To SelectedRecord:::::'+JSON.stringify(this.selectedRecords));
    let selectRecId = [];
    this.selectedRecords = [...selectRecId];
    let selRecords = this.selectedRecords;
    const selectedEvent = new CustomEvent('selected', { detail: {selRecords}, });
    // Dispatches the event.
    this.dispatchEvent(selectedEvent);
}
```

}

I should be able to add new values to the existing list.
and by doing this on the html.

```
<div class="slds-form-element__control slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon_left-right" role="none">
                        <template if:true={selectedRecords} for:each={selectedRecords} for:item="serecord">
                            <span key={serecord.recId}>
                            <lightning-pill label={serecord.recName} name={serecord.recId} onremove={removeRecord} onaddrecord={addRecord}>
                                    <lightning-icon icon-name={iconName} variant="circle" alternative-text={serecord.recName}></lightning-icon>
                                </lightning-pill>
                            </span>
                        </template>
                    </div>
```

here is the component full js

```
    import { LightningElement,api,track } from 'lwc';
import getResults from '@salesforce/apex/lwcMultiLookupController.getResults';

export default class LwcMultiSelectLookup extends LightningElement {
    @api objectName = 'Account';
    @api fieldName = 'Name';
    @api Label;
    @track searchRecords = [];
    @api selectedRecords = [];
    @api required = false;
    @api iconName = 'standard:account'
    @api LoadingText = false;
    @track txtclassname = 'slds-combobox slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click';
    @track messageFlag = false;

    searchField(event) {

        var currentText = event.target.value;
        var selectRecId = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < this.selectedRecords.length; i++){
            selectRecId.push(this.selectedRecords[i].recId);
        }
        this.LoadingText = true;
        getResults({ ObjectName: this.objectName, fieldName: this.fieldName, value: currentText, selectedRecId : selectRecId })
        .then(result => {
            this.searchRecords= result;
            this.LoadingText = false;
            
            this.txtclassname =  result.length > 0 ? 'slds-combobox slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click slds-is-open' : 'slds-combobox slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click';
            if(currentText.length > 0 && result.length == 0) {
                this.messageFlag = true;
            }
            else {
                this.messageFlag = false;
            }

            if(this.selectRecordId != null && this.selectRecordId.length > 0) {
                this.iconFlag = false;
                this.clearIconFlag = true;
            }
            else {
                this.iconFlag = true;
                this.clearIconFlag = false;
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('-------error-------------'+error);
            console.log(error);
        });
        
    }
    
   setSelectedRecord(event) {
        var recId = event.currentTarget.dataset.id;
        var selectName = event.currentTarget.dataset.name;
        let newsObject = { 'recId' : recId ,'recName' : selectName };
        this.selectedRecords.push(newsObject);
        this.txtclassname =  'slds-combobox slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click';
        let selRecords = this.selectedRecords;
        this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input').forEach(each => {
            each.value = '';
        });
        console.log('SelectedRecord:::::'+JSON.stringify(this.selectedRecords));
        const selectedEvent = new CustomEvent('selected', { detail: {selRecords}, });
        // Dispatches the event.
        this.dispatchEvent(selectedEvent);
    }

    removeRecord (event){
        let selectRecId = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < this.selectedRecords.length; i++){
            if(event.detail.name !== this.selectedRecords[i].recId)
                selectRecId.push(this.selectedRecords[i]);
        }
        this.selectedRecords = [...selectRecId];
        let selRecords = this.selectedRecords;
        const selectedEvent = new CustomEvent('selected', { detail: {selRecords}, });
        // Dispatches the event.
        this.dispatchEvent(selectedEvent);
    }

    addRecord (event) {
        var recId = event.currentTarget.dataset.id;
        var selectName = event.currentTarget.dataset.name;
        let newsObject = { 'recId' : recId ,'recName' : selectName };

        for(let i = 0; i < this.selectedRecords.length; i++) {
            if(event.detail.name !== this.selectedRecords[i].recId)
                this.selectedRecords.push(newsObject);
        }
        console.log('addRecord To SelectedRecord:::::'+JSON.stringify(this.selectedRecords));
        let selectRecId = [];
        this.selectedRecords = [...selectRecId];
        let selRecords = this.selectedRecords;
        const selectedEvent = new CustomEvent('selected', { detail: {selRecords}, });
        // Dispatches the event.
        this.dispatchEvent(selectedEvent);
    }
}
```